# How to display correct json data using django

Tags: django

Am trying to display database record as json arrays. if I run the  code below

**views.py**

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse

def read(request):
    members = Member.objects.all()
    print("success")
    jsondata = serializers.serialize('json', members)
    return HttpResponse(jsondata, content_type='application/json')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class Member(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname
```

am getting  json response as per below

```
[
{"model": "crud.member", "pk": 1, "fields": {"firstname": "Thor", "lastname": "Odinson"}},  
{"model": "crud.member", "pk": 6, "fields": {"firstname": "sdd", "lastname": "rrrrr"}}
]
```

**My Requirements:**
Here is what I want. I want to get my json responses in the following manner below

```
[
{"firstname": "Thorr", "lastname": "Odinson"},  
{"firstname": "Ann", "lastname": "bell"}
]
```

To this effect, If I try using `JsonResponse()` method as per code below, am getting error 
**'QuerySet' object is not callable**

```
def read(request):
    #response_data = {}
    response_data = []
    members = Member.objects.all()
    return JsonResponse(response_data, members)
    print("success")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the output you are looking for, calling `json.dumps()` on the output of `QuerySet.values()` should be fine:

```
members = Member.objects.values('firstname', 'lastname')
jsondata = json.dumps(list(members))
```

Comment: Please Sir, I have another issue here. can see if you can help. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318172/json-records-returns-only-one-rows-of-records-from-database-via-django