# Json Records returns only one rows of records from database via django

Tags: django

I have three records in database but json response returns only just one records.

I need to display database records via json by instantiating a variables so that instead of using database coulmn name
**firstname** and **lastname**, I can use something like **fname** and **lname** respectively when outputing json records from database.

To this effect, I have created the following code below

**views.py**

```
def read(request):
    response_data = {}
    for members in Member.objects.all():
    #members = Member.objects.all()

        response_data['fname']=members.lastname
        response_data['lname']=members.firstname
        print("successful....")
        jsondata = json.dumps([response_data])
        #jsondata = json.dumps(list([response_data]))
        return HttpResponse(jsondata, content_type='application/json')
```

**My Issue:** 
My problem is that each time the code above is run, it displays only just one records from database via json.
Eg. Here

```
[
{"fname": "Thorr", "lname": "Odinson"}
]
```

**My Requirements:**

How do I make it to loop more and display all the three records from database via json
Eg.

```
 [
    {"fname": "Thorr", "lname": "Odinson"},  
    {"fname": "Ann", "lname": "bell"},
    {"fname": "Jon", "lname": "Han"}
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you are returning a response within your loop. Instead create the response data first and the send it.

```
def read(request):
    response_data = [{'fname': m.lastname, 'lname': m.firstname} for m in Members.objects.all()]
    jsondata = json.dumps(response_data)
    return HttpResponse(jsondata, content_type='application/json')
```

Also, your logic seems to be flipping first and last names. I kept this logic to align with your code but you may want to reverse the fname and lname args.